# How to remove defaul focus visual from GridViewItem, UWP-XAML

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm writing UWP app for the Xbox using latest released public UWP SDK - v.14393.

I have some problems with styling the app - now with creating custom focus visual for GridView's GridViewItem with the template which described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx (not the 'ListViewItemExpanded')

So, the main question is - how to remove default focus visual state (red border on the screenshot) for the GridViewItem's template with the ListViewItemPresenter as a ControlTemplate.

Please refer the sample project is here - https://github.com/bondarenkod/bugs/blob/uwp-gridview-default-focus-visual/visualstatestest/visualstatestest/MainPage.xaml

[image: visual tree of the GridViewItem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red border you've seen is not a focus visual effect but a selected visual effect. To remove this border, you can set [SelectedBackground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ListViewItemPresenter#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_ListViewItemPresenter_SelectedBackground) property to `Transparent` like

```
<ListViewItemPresenter SelectedBackground="Transparent" .../>
```

Besides this property, there are several other properties like [SelectedPointerOverBackground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ListViewItemPresenter#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_ListViewItemPresenter_SelectedPointerOverBackground) and [SelectedPressedBackground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ListViewItemPresenter#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_ListViewItemPresenter_SelectedPressedBackground) may influence the color of the border. These properties are ended with "Background", you may also need to change these properties according to your requirement.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!